# User Data import through Linkedin

Tags: api, authentication, linkedin-api

I am working on user data form on my website. User will have to share info like Education, past experiences, awards, mention ( and later verified by us) 
I think it would be easier to just import this info through users' linkedIn ( They will be asked to connect their linkedIn)
 We don't wnat to incorporate Linkedin Signup/Singin. Just a Connect account.

I couldnt find this sort of linkedIn API. Has anyone used this? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a LinkedIn app and use OAuth to to connect to a user's profile. After that you can import certain fields. You'll first need to find a OAuth library for your programming language, then write custom code to do the import.

Create app:
https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer

OAuth:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2